# Add product SKU to Stripe order description with 'Stripe for Woocommerce'

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for Woocommerce https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woo-stripe-payment/

I need to change the order description that appears in the stripe Dashboard so it includes the SKU of the product(s) in the order.

I have been able to edit the description with the below filter:

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_payment_intent_args', function($args, $order){

    
    $args['description'] = sprintf('Order %s %s', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_billing_last_name());
    return $args;

},10, 2);
```

I have also found this for getting the SKU

```
$items = $order->get_items();

// Loop through ordered items
foreach ($items as $item) {
$product_id = $item['product_id'];
$product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
$sku = $product->get_sku();
}
```

However I can't workout how to now combine these so that in Stripe I get Order ID, Billing Last Name, SKU's.

I thought I'd solved this with the below but this will work but only if I have one product. I'm assigning the SKU variable in the loop but then creating the description outside of the loop which means I will only ever see the last SKU assigned in the loop.

I need a comma separated string that consists of the SKUs and then I can assign that outside of the loop but don't know what to do.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_payment_intent_args', function($args, $order){

    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through ordered items
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    }
    
    $args['description'] = sprintf('Order %s %s %s', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_billing_last_name(), $product->get_sku());
    return $args;

},10, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have been advised elsewhere so sharing in case anyone else comes across this.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_payment_intent_args', function($args, $order){

    $items = $order->get_items();
    $skus = [];
    // Loop through ordered items
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
    $skus[] = $product->get_sku();
    }
    
    $args['description'] = sprintf('Order %s %s %s', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_billing_last_name(), implode(',', $skus));
    return $args;

},10, 2);
```

Comment: It's not working. This `wc_stripe_payment_intent_args` hook is not available in the plugin docs.